# gwt return error xml tag attribute for polymer elements and no icon displayed for paper-icon-button

Tags: java, xml, maven, gwt, polymer

Good morning all {my first question on stackoverflow}

1) From my Main.ui.xml file, it seems to me that the following non-value paper-drawer-toggle tag attribute

```
<paper-drawer-panel ui:field="drawerPanel">
    ...
    <paper-icon-button ui:field="menu" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    ...
<paper-drawer-panel ui:field="drawerPanel">
```

is not tollerated by GWT as in Eclipse I get following error

> Attribute "paper-drawer-toggle" associated with an element type
>   "paper-icon-button" must be followed by the '=' character.

Anyway, Vaadin in its [Polymer guide and in tells exactly to do what I've done](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel) tells exactly to do what I've written in my Main.ui.xml file.

2) Moreover, even if I put paper-drawer-toggle="" in the Main.ui.xml file, it turns out that no icon is in the page in paper-icon-button. I've also tried to put scr="..." attribute with URL to a png image but no icon the page yet.

so, for points 1) and 2) ...
Am I missing something?
Or is to be told GWT to ignore Polymer XML tags from its compiling action?
Or whatelse?

Any suggestion, information and/or solution is warmly welcomed.

---

---

When I use Windows command prompt and execute:

```
mvn GWT:run
```

and after I open browser with target served html page. Then I see "compiling Todolist" message in browser page and then "failed" link and "Try again" button. While in command prompt, meanwhile I got:

```
[INFO] GET /recompile/todolist
[INFO]    Job org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList_1_1
[INFO]       starting job: org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList_1_1
[INFO]       binding: user.agent=safari
[INFO]       Compiling module org.gwtproject.tutorial.TodoList
[INFO]          Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.gwtproject.tutori
al.client.Main.MainUiBinder'
[INFO]             Rebinding org.gwtproject.tutorial.client.Main.MainUiBinder
[INFO]                Invoking generator com.google.gwt.uibinder.rebind.UiBinder
Generator
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Attribute name "paper-drawer-toggle" associated
 with an element type "paper-icon-button" must be followed by the ' = ' characte
r.
[INFO]                   [ERROR] Error parsing XML (line 62): Attribute name "pa
per-drawer-toggle" associated with an element type "paper-icon-button" must be f
ollowed by the ' = ' character.
[INFO]          [ERROR] Errors in 'org/gwtproject/tutorial/client/Main.java'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Line 28: Failed to resolve 'org.gwtproject.tutorial.c
lient.Main.MainUiBinder' via deferred binding
[INFO]          [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never com
mitted (did you forget to call commit()?)
[INFO]             [WARN] org.gwtproject.tutorial.client.Main_MainUiBinderImpl
[INFO]          Unification traversed 12962 fields and methods and 1077 types. 1
052 are considered part of the current module and 1052 had all of their fields a
nd methods traversed.
[INFO]       [ERROR] Compiler returned false
[INFO]       [WARN] recompile failed
[INFO]       [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

I'm following [this TodoList GWT 2.70 Polymer 1.0 tutorial](https://github.com/manolo/gwt-polymer-todo-list/tree/master/elements-todo-list) using Apache Maven 3.3.9 in Eclipse Java EE Luna 4.4.2
Any file I have got is quite equal to the ones in the tutorial (equal but the project paths).

I'm using following confiuration pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.gwtproject.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-polymer-elements-todo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.2.0-alpha3</version>
  <name>GWT Polymer TodoList tutorial App (elements version).</name>

  <properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <gwtPolymerVersion>${project.version}</gwtPolymerVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-codeserver</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin.polymer</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtPolymerVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>

        <outputDirectory>target/gwt-polymer-elements-todo-1.0.2.0-alpha3/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>TodoListElements.html</runTarget>
          <compileReport>false</compileReport>
          <jsInteropMode>JS</jsInteropMode>
          <optimizationLevel>9</optimizationLevel>
          <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
          <disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata>
          <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
          <closureCompiler>true</closureCompiler>
          <bindAddress>0.0.0.0</bindAddress>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}${project.build.finalName}</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                 <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `paper-drawer-toggle="paper-drawer-toggle"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the error message just assign any string like

```
paper-drawer-toggle="true"
```

The `<paper-drawer-panel>` shouldn't care about the value, only whether the attribute is there or not.

<strike>The error message you got in Eclipse doesn't make sense to me. I can tell you for sure that `<some-tag-name="foo">` doesn't make sense. Try to ignore the warning, Your Eclipse might not recognize custom tags.</strike>

I guess you are missing the icons import

```
<link rel="import" href="../../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
```

See also the demo of the `<paper-icon-button>` https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-icon-button/blob/master/demo/index.html#L17

Comment: It totally does make sense: UiBinder files are XML, not HTML, so they must be well formed.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Thanks for the correction. You are right of course. I didn't read properly. The error message is about the attribute `paper-drawer-toggle` not `paper-drawer-panel'.

Comment: thanks @GunterZochbauer for reply and suggestions
1) `paper-drawer-toggle=""` worked in way that I get non-value `paper-drawer-toggle=""` attribute for `<paper-drawer-panel>` element in HTML
2) I do actually import iron-icons.html file via Javascript compiled Java code in file TodoList.java  
    `Polymer.importHref(
      Arrays.asList(
        "iron-icons/iron-icons.html",`  
and I get in HTML file:  
   ` <link rel="import" href="http://192.168.42.229:9876/todolist/bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">`  
anything I can do?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: I found the solution: the Polymer element `<paper-icon-button>` import reference were not included in my HTML page. So I added related import in Java:  
`Polymer.importHref(Arrays.asList(..., PaperIconButtonElement.SRC),...); `
and now I get also  
`<link rel="import" href="http://192.168.42.229:9876/todolist/bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">`  
in HTML page. So now when when application switches to narrow template, the menu drawer disappears and the paper-icon-button drawer menu appears and when I click it, the drawer menu slide in.

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial has two options: elements and widgets.
if you use the element approach just adding `paper-drawer-toggle=""` works, but if you use the widget approach you have to use `attributes=""`

```
<p:PaperIconButton ui:field="menu" icon="menu" attributes="paper-drawer-toggle"/>
```